# Semaphore doesn't work in C. Why?

Tags: c, multithreading, cygwin, semaphore

Firstly, I'm Italian and sorry for my bad English.
Anyway, I should do this exercise:
"Write in C a programm which generate a thread. The main shows odd number from 1 to 9, the thread shows even number from 2 to 10. Synchronize the main and the thread with semaphores"

I have written the pseudocode in this way:

```
//semaphores
semParent = free
semChild = busy

main
  generate thread "child"
  for i=1 to 9 step 2
    P(semParent)
    print i
    V(semChild)
  end for
end main

child
  for i=2 to 10 step 2
    P(semChild)
    print i
    V(semParent)
end child
```

And this is how I have implemented in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t semParent;
pthread_mutex_t semChild = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* functionChild (void* arg) {
    for(int i=2; i<=10; i+=2) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semChild);
        printf("CHILD: %d\n",i);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semParent);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {    
    pthread_t child;
    pthread_create(&child, NULL, &functionChild, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&semParent, NULL);
    for(int i=1; i<=9; i+=2) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&semParent);
        printf("PARENT : %d\n",i);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&semChild);
    }
    pthread_join(child, NULL);
}
```

But the output is always different whenever I run the program. 
What's wrong? 

I use CygWin64 Terminal in Windows 10 64 bit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to achieve monotonically increased output values you should pass "stick" from one thread to other repeatedly. Look for condition variables.

Comment: @Serhio why would he use condition variables if the problem asks him to use semaphores? His pseudocode is okay, it's just the C translation that is wrong.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini Mutex is often treated as binary semaphore (only two counter values: 1 or 0), so IMO translation is quite legal. And  condition variables are required to "unfreeze" waiting thread, since mutexes don't provide such ability.

Comment: @The97Pasquale2 your code doesn't have any critical section, you merely increase a local var `i` which is independent in each thread - you don't need any lock in that case. The `i` should be global, only one mutex is required to protect it.

Comment: But his problem asks him to use semaphores. If I were grading it, a solution using mutex/condvar would be pretty obviously a failure.

Answer (score 1):

A `pthread_mutex_t` is not a semaphore (though a semaphore can be used as a mutex if you do a "V" to initialize it to "free").  The semaphore API is `sem_init`, `sem_post` and `sem_wait`.

By using `pthread_mutex_unlock` on a mutex that was locked by another thread, your program is triggering undefined behavior.

Comment: `sem_*()` family is not a pthread API, it is designed for inter-process communication.

Comment: @Serhio The functions [provided in `semaphore.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/semaphore.h.html) are designed for both inter- and *intra*-process communication, per [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_init.html).  They are quite appropriate for use here.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: @Serhio perhaps you were confusing it with `semget`/`semctl`? ("System V semaphores")

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause of the problem you are experiencing now, but you should never use printf() in a multithreaded program. printf() writes to a buffer and doesn't always print to the screen right away. Instead you should use sprintf() and write:

```
char buff[20];
sprintf("PARENT: %d\n", i);
write(1, buff, strlen(buff));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that `pthread_mutex_init(&semParent, NULL)` with NULL attributes and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` have the same effect, which is both locks are initialised to unlocked. Your problem though does not have a critical section with the strict meaning. So a better solution whould be condition variables as @Serhio mentioned. You can also check out semaphores http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html which give bigger freedom and can also have the functionality of mutexes.